# How to transfer from Galaxy 5 to PC without loss of quality?

Tags: file-transfer, android

Photos on my Samsung G5 preview screen look much brighter, so much more vivid and saturated, than on my PC screen after I transfer them. Why? Does it have to do with a different color space? How can I transfer them to my PC and edit them in PS CC without any loss of quality?

Comment: You won't loose quality by just transferring it. All the data is saved on the file. You might want to look at a better monitor or calibrating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no quality loss. The displays are simply different hardware and calibrated differently. Mobile displays often over compensate in the areas you mentioned since they are viewed in poor conditions and also because most people like that, and are not setup for accurate work.

Comment: Yep - and not just 'compensate', they intentionally oversaturate or turn up the vibrance, so that the picture looks more attractive than competitor in store. Same thing happens with TVs, at least most of them have controls to remove all 'auto-enhancing' effects.